# NetworkX, Scatter, TikzPlotLib.save >>> unexpected results

Tags: tikz-pgf, python

I use python to make a TEX file.
The python figure and the figure in the PDF generated by TexStudio are different.
Why, and how to solve this?

This python code returns a figure...

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tikzplotlib

f = plt.figure()
G=nx.dodecahedral_graph()
edges=nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos=nx.spring_layout(G))

plt.xlim(left = -5)
plt.ylim(bottom = -5)
plt.xlim(right = 5)
plt.ylim(top = 5)

plt.scatter(4,4,10)

filename = "../04_paper/v2/figures/test_0001.tex"
tikzplotlib.save(filename, figurewidth = '\\textwidth')


with open(filename, 'r') as file :
filedata = file.read()
filedata = filedata.replace('marker=', 'mark=')
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
file.write(filedata)
```

[image]

The python code also generates a tex file.
I have a small document in which I use this tex file.
This is the document...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \input{figures/test_0001.tex}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The PDF looks like this....

[image]

An the TEX file looks like this ....

```
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.8.5.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}

\begin{axis}[
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
width=\textwidth,
x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
xmin=-5, xmax=5,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
ymin=-5, ymax=5,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.449869419045689,-0.340116789785537)
--(axis cs:0.166604320932147,-0.461802304323172);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.449869419045689,-0.340116789785537)
--(axis cs:-0.778421879619552,-0.661338963091823);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.449869419045689,-0.340116789785537)
--(axis cs:-0.490933132460653,0.31086179305115);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.166604320932147,-0.461802304323172)
--(axis cs:0.367402087957061,-0.917746512767419);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.166604320932147,-0.461802304323172)
--(axis cs:0.500170347058356,0.0617035911381695);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.367402087957061,-0.917746512767419)
--(axis cs:-0.249244806794993,-1);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.367402087957061,-0.917746512767419)
--(axis cs:0.862438543757522,-0.525764709650988);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.249244806794993,-1)
--(axis cs:-0.106828666321425,-0.574636278402222);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.249244806794993,-1)
--(axis cs:-0.778421879619552,-0.661338963091823);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.106828666321425,-0.574636278402222)
--(axis cs:0.489836859592617,-0.310396080328135);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.106828666321425,-0.574636278402222)
--(axis cs:-0.493334975922122,-0.0668474818886589);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.489836859592617,-0.310396080328135)
--(axis cs:0.862438543757522,-0.525764709650988);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.489836859592617,-0.310396080328135)
--(axis cs:0.451257849459473,0.339898321728359);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.862438543757522,-0.525764709650988)
--(axis cs:0.988548909684843,0.086531346873156);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.988548909684843,0.086531346873156)
--(axis cs:0.500170347058356,0.0617035911381695);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.988548909684843,0.086531346873156)
--(axis cs:0.771524093628576,0.670403541143043);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.500170347058356,0.0617035911381695)
--(axis cs:0.110458558654231,0.567120826603463);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.110458558654231,0.567120826603463)
--(axis cs:-0.490933132460653,0.31086179305115);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.110458558654231,0.567120826603463)
--(axis cs:0.244193107421853,0.997908147098971);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.490933132460653,0.31086179305115)
--(axis cs:-0.86537538524157,0.531439446332259);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.86537538524157,0.531439446332259)
--(axis cs:-0.36833089642205,0.91611475961209);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.86537538524157,0.531439446332259)
--(axis cs:-0.985473024134406,-0.0831182352731083);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.36833089642205,0.91611475961209)
--(axis cs:0.244193107421853,0.997908147098971);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.36833089642205,0.91611475961209)
--(axis cs:-0.164622492184216,0.459785581930401);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.244193107421853,0.997908147098971)
--(axis cs:0.771524093628576,0.670403541143043);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.771524093628576,0.670403541143043)
--(axis cs:0.451257849459473,0.339898321728359);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.451257849459473,0.339898321728359)
--(axis cs:-0.164622492184216,0.459785581930401);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.164622492184216,0.459785581930401)
--(axis cs:-0.493334975922122,-0.0668474818886589);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.493334975922122,-0.0668474818886589)
--(axis cs:-0.985473024134406,-0.0831182352731083);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.985473024134406,-0.0831182352731083)
--(axis cs:-0.778421879619552,-0.661338963091823);

\addplot [draw=none, mark=*, draw=color0, fill=color0, colormap/viridis]
table{%
x                      y
0 -0.5
0.13260155 -0.5
0.259789935392427 -0.447316845794121
0.353553390593274 -0.353553390593274
0.447316845794121 -0.259789935392427
0.5 -0.13260155
0.5 0
0.5 0.13260155
0.447316845794121 0.259789935392427
0.353553390593274 0.353553390593274
0.259789935392427 0.447316845794121
0.13260155 0.5
0 0.5
-0.13260155 0.5
-0.259789935392427 0.447316845794121
-0.353553390593274 0.353553390593274
-0.447316845794121 0.259789935392427
-0.5 0.13260155
-0.5 0
-0.5 -0.13260155
-0.447316845794121 -0.259789935392427
-0.353553390593274 -0.353553390593274
-0.259789935392427 -0.447316845794121
-0.13260155 -0.5
0 -0.5
0 -0.5
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Why are the python plot and the pdf different?
An how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the options in the following line:

```
\addplot [draw=none, mark=*, draw=color0, fill=color0, colormap/viridis]
```

by:

```
\addplot [draw=none]
```

the result is the same:

[image]

You could also adapt the axis: `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` to get the same view.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. However I do not see the dot at coordinates (4,4). Please have a look at the first picture I posted.

Comment: Since in the generated code, there is no coordinate (4,4), I think you have to add it manually. It seems to be a tikzplotlib problem, so maybe you should ask there.

Comment: OK, I'll try there. Thanks. https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib/issues/381